# Angular Not Binding with Jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express

I am having some trouble getting simple binding to work using Angular and Jade. I have read previous answers which suggested moving the JavaScript references to the end of the document. Can anyone see any obvious errors or have any suggestions ?

Some file angular.jade

```
extends layout

block content
 div.container
 input(type='text' ng-model='yourName')
 h3 hello {{yourName}}
 include includes/footer
```

Then my footer.jade

```
#footer
   script(src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js')
   script(src='//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js')
   script(src="/socket.io/socket.io.js")
   script(src="/javascripts/script.js")
   script(src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js')
```

I moved these into the footer to see if that would make a difference they were in the head section of the layout.jade previously

The layout is

```
doctype 5
html
  head(ng-app)
    title Chat
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet',     href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css")


  body
   div(ng-view)
    block content
```

**UPDATE**

Solved my moving ng-app to body instead of head and got rid of div(ng-view). Not looked at Angular code so not sure why this is so ....

Comment: Missing comma between attributes, typo or in actual code? `input(type='text' ng-model='yourName')` ??

Comment: Comma was missing, but does not make a difference BTW output HTML was the same in both cases

Comment: It makes a huge difference, FYI. Add that comma to start. Check your console, any errors?

Comment: Also, what is inside `script.js`?

Comment: Comma added, no errors, script.js has some Jquery, socket.io and a document ready function ...

Comment: Where's your angular code? Also, using Angular, you probably shouldn't have standalone jQuery like that, but that's not the issue at hand/

Comment: Angular code is posted above using Jade - top code block (template)

Comment: Are those double curly braces appearing in the rendered HTML?

Comment: yes they are in the html

Comment: Try bumping the Angular script to the top, Angular isn't loading right for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I'd import `angular.min.js` first (instead of importing it last). Also, did you check the console for any errors?

Comment: I removed all the other javascript references except Angular, same thing

Comment: try moving ng-app to body instead of head

Comment: moving it to body and now there is only a `<div ng-view>` which is empty

Comment: any ideas why that happens ?

Comment: Angular only 'handles' the element you declare it on. I'm guessing, the angular module (and hence its controllers and services) were only limited to the head element and not the body.